# Deploying dependent (external) war in in eclipse wtp project

Tags: eclipse, war, eclipse-wtp

Its been a while since I used eclipse. I have a webapp that is dependant on another .WAR (geoserver.war). I use eclipse Juno J2EE package, and what I'm failing to configure is to have tomcat deploy my dependant .WAR along with the project built webapp.

I've ended up copying geoserver.war to ..\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\webapps, so now its deployed whenever I run the app on the server, but this is obviously not the proper way.

How to configure eclipse tomcat integration to deploy the external war as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and and I fixed using WTP and Maven.
What I did is to create a dummy war project with a single dependency that is the war that I wanted to use.
Using this technique, the imported war would be used as an overlay war and, because of the project, eclipse will allow you to add it as a module to a server configuration.

In details, the pom will look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>your-module-name</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your.parent</artifactId>
    <version>your.version</version>
  </parent>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>war.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>war.id</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

After that, you import it as an existing maven project and voila`, the war is now available as a module to add to any server configuration.